# Install EXE as service on Windows 2008 Server

Tags: unauthorized, instsrv

Sorry for bad english. I'm trying to install an executable as a service using instsrv.exe, here is what I tried:

**instsrv "Gestion1" MROOneService.exe**

That is the message that i get when trying:

"You are not authorized to do this - please contact your system Administrator"

Someon can help. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

you should run the command as an administrator

I don't have Windows 2008 with me at the moment but I think you right click on the DOS command line icon from your start menu then choose "Run as administrator...". You then run this command inside the administrator dos command line prompt.

Answer (score -1):

You need the command line or the call to run as administrator. It is not enough to be logged in as administrator and run the command / statement.