# How can I make an .exe python program in windows works like a daemon?

Tags: python, windows, task, daemon

I have a python windows console application in a .exe packaged by cx_freeze. It works fine when called by Windows Command Line. What I want to do now is simple: Get this .exe and turn it a daemon service in Windows (Something like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)#Implementation_in_MS-DOS_and_Microsoft_Windows) that runs in background near the windows clock (like DropBox, for example). So, the question is: What is the simplest and best way to achieve it? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085694/whats-the-simplest-way-to-put-a-python-script-into-the-system-tray-windows

Answer (score 0):

There are one or two exe files that can prime another executable as a service. Here are a few links:

[Install EXE as service on Windows 2008 Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309781/install-exe-as-service-on-windows-2008-server)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192

There are many more. The search string I used in Google was "install an exe as a service windows"

J